# How to reuse html template within the same view and controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form template as shown below.

```
<form editable-form name="tableForm">
    <table>
       <tr style="font-weight: bold">

           // Column names here....

       </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="user in list1>

          //Column values here ...

       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I want to reuse this template for creating multiple table within same page/controller using different model e.g. list1, list2, list3 etc.

How can I pass the name of the form and model dynamically so that all these tables's operation works independently of each other and still I need not repeat same html with different form name and list model inside my view.html?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look in `directive`.

Comment: Thanks @StepanKasyanenko. I am looking into that.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to Your angular application.

First, You have to move Your html to a separate file, then declare a directive:

```
.directive('tableform', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      list: '='
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '<path to html file>'
  };
});
```

and, finally, You can use it like this:

```
<tableform list="list1" />
<tableform list="list2" />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Controller:**

```
scope.dataLists = [ [list1], [list2], [list3] ]
```

**Main View:**

```
<form editable-form name="tableForm">
    <div ng-repeat="list in dataLists" ng-include="'reuseable-table.html'"></div>
</form>
```

**reuseable-table.html:**

```
<table>
  <tr style="font-weight: bold">

  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="user in list">
  
  </tr>
</table>
```